# How do I download facetime on my first generation iPad

Tags: ios

I have version 5.1.1 iPad.  How do I download FaceTime.

Comment: Your iPad doesn't have a camera.

Comment: You can't download FaceTime as a separate application, it comes with the device, if that device is capable.

Answer (score 2):

You can't download FaceTime as a separate application, it comes with the device, if that device is capable.

Comment: From comment by [Tetsujin](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately this is no longer possible. Though you can turn it into a phone if it's a cellular model.